# Obtener información desde HTML usando Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Tengo un problema al obtener la información de una página HTML usando Jsoup y el método `.select()`. El problema es que cuando se cumpla la condición, no quiero que me coja esa información. Me intento explicar, con el siguiente código, si el precio tiene el valor `-`, miro si en el código de la página aparece si es parte de un bundle, de la siguiente forma:

```
try {
   String bundle = doc.select(".context-product-placement-data .cli_product_message").first().text();     
   if (item.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_NORMAL + " "+ e.getKey()).equals("-") && (bundle.contains("bundles") || bundle.contains("paquetes") || bundle.contains("recopilaciones") || bundle.contains("번들로 이동") || bundle.contains("跳到套件組合") 
      || bundle.contains("pacotes") || bundle.contains("пакетам") || bundle.contains("Csomagok"))) {
      item.getValues().put(Constants.PRICE_NORMAL + " "+ e.getKey(), "Only With Bundle");                                          
   } 
} catch (NullPointerException ex) {

}
```

El código funciona bien por lo general, el problema es que en el siguiente caso: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/p/motogp-17/bv559lh6rts1, aparece la frase "Available only as part of a bundle" en un div que está oculto.

Cómo le puedo decir que coja la información con esa ruta, pero que además no tenga la clase `hidden`?

Lo único que se me ocurre es volver a ejecutar el condicional después, pero de la siguiente forma:

```
try {
       String bundle = doc.select(".context-product-placement-data .hidden").first().text(); //no me devuelve ningún resultado    
       if ((bundle.contains("bundles") || bundle.contains("paquetes") || bundle.contains("recopilaciones") || bundle.contains("번들로 이동") || bundle.contains("跳到套件組合") 
          || bundle.contains("pacotes") || bundle.contains("пакетам") || bundle.contains("Csomagok"))) {
          item.getValues().put(Constants.PRICE_NORMAL + " "+ e.getKey(), "-");                                          
       } 
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {

    }
```

Es decir, una segunda comprobación para ver si la ruta existe, si existe es que la información está en oculto por lo tanto no debe tenerla en cuenta, y cambio el precio a "-".

Comment: No existe ninguna clase/interfaz nativa del JDK que tenga el método `select` y reciba lo que indicas. ¿Será que estás trabajando con jsoup o un framework similar para parsear HTML?

Comment: Si, uso jSoup para parsear HTML. @LuiggiMendoza